# What DevOps Engineer would like to see in light version of cool automation tooling

Tags: deployment, web-deployment

I'm thinking about creating the ultimative DevOps deployment delivery tooling, dear DevOps fellows what do you think such tooling have to include?

Answer (score 3):

I'd advise that you checkout the existing options, before writing something entirely new.
That way you can improve an existing project or better justify your entirely new effort.

By way of example my latest deployment toy is [rundeck](http://rundeck.org/). I love it's simplicity, ease of setup and it's ability to interoperate other Devops tools like Jenkins, Chef and Puppet.